# Recuperar ciertos datos de un json ajax/jquery laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo una vista en la cual mediante un select A (Bodegas) realizo la carga de otro select con cierta informacion (Select Materiales), pero ahora necesito que al seleccionar un item del Select B (Materiales) se me muestre un alerto o un input con la cantidad de materiales disponibles.
En mi vista blade trabajo con jquery/ajax para traer la informacion via json y procesarla.

La respuesta del ajax es asi:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "material_id": 1,
      "nombre_producto": "ROUTER INALAMBRICO HUAWEI",
      "servicio_id": 1,
      "seriado": 0,
      "servicio": "HFC",
      "bodega_id": 1,
      "cantidad": 30,
      "nombre_bodega": "STGO-NVOS-01",
      "tipo_bodega": "Bodega Nuevos"
    },
```

Esta es la funcion que mediante ajax trae la informacion de la base de datos y llena el select A (Bodegas) (es el select que al seleccionar un item, me carga el select de los materiales):

```
$('#bodega').on('change', function(){
            var bodega_id = $(this).val();
            var servicio_id = $('#servicio_id').val();

            $('#bodega_id').val(bodega_id);
            //$('#tecnico_id').val(tecnico_id);
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ url('/bodega/material/servicio') }}"+`/${bodega_id}`+`/${servicio_id}`,
                method:"get",
                //data:{stock:cantidad},
                success:function(result){
                    //console.log(result.data)
                    var opciones = '';
                    var opciones = '<option value="">--Seleccione Materiales a Asignar--</option>';
                    result.data.forEach(element => {
                        opciones += `<option value="${element.material_id}" data-seriado="${element.seriado}">${element.nombre_producto}</option>`;
                    });
                    $("#materiales").html(opciones)
                }
            })
        });
```

Y el codigo que uso para el select b (Materiales, que es donde quiero que al seleccionar un material de este select me muestre la cantidad que hay de ese producto):

```
function agregar(){
            //e.preventDefault();
            var repetido = false;
            var material_id = $('#materiales').val();

            //var material_id = $('#materiales').val();
            material = $("#materiales option:selected").text();
            cantidad = $('#cantidad').val();
            serie = $("#materiales option:selected").data('seriado');
            v= $('#material_id').val(material_id);
            $('#seriados').val(serie);
            for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
                if(ids[i] == material_id){
                    repetido = true;
                }
            }

            if( material_id != "" && cantidad != "" && cantidad > 0  && !repetido){
                ids.push(material_id);
                //console.log(material_id);
                if (serie == 0) {
                    //EN ESTA LINEA ESTA EL CODIGO QUE ABRE EL MODAL CON LA VARIABLE material_id
                    var id = parseInt( $('#materiales').val() );
                    console.log(id);
                    var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td><td><a href=""  data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="modal('+material_id+');">Asignar Series</button></a></td></tr>';
                } else {
                    var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">No Seriable</button></td></tr>';
                }
                //var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="material_id[]" value="'+material_id+'">'+material+'</td><td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td></tr>';
                $('#detalles').append(fila);
                $('#guardar').show();
                cont++;
                limpiarControles();
                }else
                {
                    alert("No se han seleccionado materiales o el material ya esta en la lista");
                    $('#guardar').show();
                }
        }
```

Saludos a todos